# Same procedure doesn't work called in a Thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, libgosu

I have a problem with Thread in Ruby.
It's the first time I use Threads, so maybe I omit something important.

I have this procedure:

```
  def define_action(field)
    false if field.nil? || field.empty?
    puts field.empty?          <---- ONLY FOR DEBUG
    case field['special']
    when 'signpost'
      typewriter_animation(field['message'])
    else
      typewriter_animation("TO DO ... add action for #{field['special']}") 
    end
  end
```

`typewriter_animation` clean a field, puts a text and wait 5 seconds before clear field again.

I use `define_action` in a Thread

```
   @timer = Thread.new do
    @engine.define_action(@map.next_field_coordinates)
  end
```

When `field` is `empty` (i see `true` in prompt) I except nothing as result, but the procedure continue and print on screen "TO DO ... add action for"

The same code without Thread work perfectly, but obviously stop screen for 5 seconds.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code, but this is not the first time you've ever used a thread: It merely is the first time you've ever used _more than one_ thread. All of the code you've ever written up 'till now has been running on some program's _main thread_, and there is absolutely no difference between how code works on the main thread vs. how it works on any other thread. Threading only gets interesting when you have two or more threads that share the same data or otherwise communicate with each other. (Which, of course, is most of the time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guard clause is missing a `return`.

```
def define_action(field)
  false if field.nil? || field.empty? # this line does nothing
  ...
end
```

Should probably be:

```
def define_action(field)
  return false if field.nil? || field.empty?
  ...
end
```

I don't see how threads would make any difference.

Comment: Yes, I miss the return, a stupid oversight error, now it's works! Thank's for your help.